# Common WPF style with different bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to utilise the following style on multiple ellipse in my application. Is there an easier way of making the style common but change the binding? I would prefer not replicate the same code over and over again.

```
<Style TargetType="Ellipse" x:Key="TeamColors">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ColorNo}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ColorNo}" Value="2">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ColorNo}" Value="3">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Lime"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ColorNo}" Value="4">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ColorNo}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="Ellipse" x:Key="TeamColors2">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ColorNo2}" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Red"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ColorNo2}" Value="2">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ColorNo2}" Value="3">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Lime"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ColorNo2}" Value="4">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Black"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ColorNo2}" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Gray"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Use a Binding Converter?

Comment: @Clemens Do you know of a way for the style to pull value from the implementation of the style? If so, to your point, the style's binding could be bound to the ColorNo[x] for each ColorNo implementation that uses the style.

Comment: This feels like you are going down the wrong path. Why not simply bind to `ColorNo` or `ColorNo2` one level higher and use `Path=.` in your Style?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Path= is not available to me in the level higher. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there an easier way of making the style common but change the binding?

I am afraid not. You can't "inherit" a `DataTrigger` and change only the binding path in XAML. This is not supported.

What you could consider to do is to create the styles programmatically using a programming language like C#:

```
private static Style CreateStyle(string bindingPath)
{
    const string xaml = "<Style xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\" TargetType=\"Ellipse\">" +
        "<Style.Triggers>" +
            "<DataTrigger Binding=\"{{Binding Path={0}}}\" Value=\"1\">" +
             "   <Setter Property=\"Fill\" Value=\"Red\"></Setter>" +
            "</DataTrigger>" +
            "<DataTrigger Binding=\"{{Binding Path={0}}}\" Value=\"2\">" +
            "    <Setter Property=\"Fill\" Value=\"Yellow\"></Setter>" +
            "</DataTrigger>" +
            "<DataTrigger Binding=\"{{Binding Path={0}}}\" Value=\"3\">" +
            "    <Setter Property=\"Fill\" Value=\"Lime\"></Setter>" +
            "</DataTrigger>" +
            "<DataTrigger Binding=\"{{Binding Path={0}}}\" Value=\"4\">" +
            "    <Setter Property=\"Fill\" Value=\"Black\"></Setter>" +
            "</DataTrigger>" +
            "<DataTrigger Binding=\"{{Binding Path={0}}}\" Value=\"0\">" +
            "    <Setter Property=\"Fill\" Value=\"Gray\"></Setter>" +
            "</DataTrigger>" +
        "</Style.Triggers>" +
    "</Style>";

    return System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(string.Format(xaml, bindingPath)) as Style;
}
```

**Sample Usage:**

```
Style style1 = CreateStyle("ColorNo");
Style style2 = CreateStyle("ColorNo2");
Application.Current.Resources.Add("TeamColors", style);
Application.Current.Resources.Add("TeamColors2", style2);
```